# VBA for Filter and Save Data in new file

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to create macro to filter the data and save new file for each filter criteria

Have got below code but I am getting compile error : wrong number of arguments or invalid property assigned on below line

```
Set filteredData = dataRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(dataRange.Rows.Count - 1, dataRange.Columns.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

At .resize
```

Below is the entire code.

```
Sub FilterAndSave()
Dim filterRange As Range, dataRange As Range, filteredData As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim folderPath As String, fileName As String

'set filter range and data range
Set filterRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A8")
Set dataRange = Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'turn off alerts and screen updating
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'loop through each filter criteria
For i = 1 To filterRange.Rows.Count
    'set filter
    dataRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterRange.Cells(i, 1).Value
    
    'check if any cells are visible
    On Error Resume Next
    Set filteredData = dataRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(dataRange.Rows.Count - 1, dataRange.Columns.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not filteredData Is Nothing Then
        'copy and save filtered data
        folderPath = filterRange.Cells(i, 1).Value & "\"
        If Len(Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir folderPath
        fileName = filterRange.Cells(i, 1).Value & ".xlsx"
        filteredData.Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs folderPath & fileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        filteredData.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

'turn on alerts and screen updating
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'check if any data is left
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(dataRange) > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Some data is not filtered", vbExclamation
End If
End Sub
```

I want macro to check all the filter criteria and save file for each filtered data and at the end it should give msg box if any data left which is not in filter criteria

Comment: At the point where your code errors, hit debug and then check the size/address of `dataRange`. There's nothing wrong with the syntax of the line itself, so there must be something in the parameters. Perhaps the filter returns no matched rows for one of the `filterRange` being passed?

Comment: Yes, there might be somecases where all 8 criteria available in range of A1 to A8 will not be available in the data

Answer (score 0):

Your loop needs to deal with the possibility that no rows are returned by the filter, ***before*** attempting to load that range to a Range object. One method would be to alter your loop like so:

```
For i = 1 To filterRange.Rows.Count
    'set filter
    dataRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterRange.Cells(i, 1).Value
    
    'if more than 1 row (just the header) visible..
    If dataRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address <> dataRange.Rows(1).Address Then
    
        Set filteredData = dataRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(dataRange.Rows.Count - 1, dataRange.Columns.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        'copy and save filtered data
        folderPath = filterRange.Cells(i, 1).Value & "\"
        If Len(Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir folderPath
        Filename = filterRange.Cells(i, 1).Value & ".xlsx"
        filteredData.Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs folderPath & Filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        filteredData.EntireRow.Delete

    End If
Next i
```